# Query builder don't accept onlyTrashed()

Tags: mysql, laravel

I'm a beginner and cant find a solution to my problem. I trying to get "onlyTrashed" from my DB but Laravel 8 don't accept my query commands :( I tried many scenarios but unsuccessful.

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use App\Models\Category;

class CategoryController extends Controller{   
 public function AllCat(){

        $categories = $trashCat = DB::table('categories')
            ->join('users','categories.user_id','users.id')
            ->select('categories.*','users.name')
            ->latest()
            ->paginate(5);
          
           //$categories = Category::latest()->paginate(5);
          // $trashCat = Category::onlyTrashed()->latest()->paginate(3);
            
        return view('admin.category.index', compact('trashCat','categories'));

public function SoftDelete($id){
     $delete = Category::find($id);`enter code here`
     return Redirect()->back()->wiht('success',' Category Delete Successfuly');

Route::get('/softdelete/category/{id}', [CategoryController::class,'SoftDelete']);
```

Comment: Welcome to SO ... what isn't working with using `onlyTrashed`?

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that your model imports and uses `SoftDeletes` trait to implement soft delete in your model and make sure that your table has `deleted_at` field, your model may look like below codes.

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

class Category extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes;
```

And in your `SoftDelete` function within the controller, I think you miss `delete()` function, your function should look like:

```
public function SoftDelete($id) {
    $delete = Category::find($id)->delete();
    return redirect()->back()->with('success',' Category Delete Successfully');
}
```

Once you implement `SoftDeletes` trait into your model, `delete()` function should mark deleted by filling the `deleted_at` with timestamp or DateTime automatically. Once you implement the above codes, `onlyTrashed()` should work.

```
$categories = Category::latest()->paginate(5);
$trashCat = Category::onlyTrashed()->latest()->paginate(3);
```